# What does **dict mean in python formatting expression?

Tags: python

I'm learning formatting expressions from a book and i have a question:

```
'{num} = {title}'.format(**dict(num=7, title='Strings'))
```

in the line above why are there two * before dict?? what do they represent?

the book didn't even mention this type of formatting expression and suddenly it was in the examples!!

Comment: While the linked duplicate does indeed explain the `**`, the real thing to know about your specific example is that the `dict()` is unnecessary. You'd get the exact same results with `format(num=7, title='Strings')`. Creating a dict just to immediately unpack it is silly (it might have made sense if it was a dict comprehension).

Comment: This is also a patently ridiculous use, since they're passing keyword args to make, then unpack a `dict`, when they could just pass the keyword args directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The Principles

Python functions allow keyword arguments. For example this function:

```
def sub(a, b):
    return a - b
```

can be called like this:

```
>>> sub(b=10, a=4)
-6
```

If you have the arguments in a dictionary:

```
>>> args = {'a': 4, 'b': 10}
```

you can use the `**`  syntax to achieve the same:

```
>>> sub(**args)
-6
```

This is called unpacking because the items in the dictionary are used individually as arguments.

### Your Example

Your example is over complicated. This would work:

```
'{num} = {title}'.format(num=7, title='Strings')
```

No need for using `**` and a dictionary. The `format()` methods works like normal function and can be used with keyword arguments directly. The values `7` and `Strings` are put into a dictionary just be taken out again immediately.